# Fragment containing lots of TextViews opens slow

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

Homepage Fragment contains a recyclerView. For every recyclerView item a new fragment opens.

[image]

The topmost two fragments contain lots of text.

First one uses TextViews -

```
<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
tools:context=".FirstFragment"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Unit 1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
        android:background="@color/blackColor"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="@string/pink_one"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Unit 2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
        android:background="@color/blackColor"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="@string/pink_two"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Unit 3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
        android:background="@color/blackColor"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="@string/pink_three"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Unit 4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
        android:background="@color/blackColor"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="@string/pink_four"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="@string/pink_five"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="@string/pink_six"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="@string/pink_seven"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="@string/pink_eight"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="@string/pink_nine"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="@string/pink_ten"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="@string/pink_eleven"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Second one uses a webView file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SecondFragment">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I thought using webView will give better performance but it's also slow(but better than lots of textViews).

I guess, First one takes approx 4-5 seconds and the Second one 3-4 seconds.
I don't want it to be so slow.

What can be the most efficient way to do this?

**Update:**
I have decided to use WebViews.
Why is that after opening my app for the first time only a WebView will load slow, after that it Or any other WebView will load quickly?

**Edit:**
I @sela said, My main mistake was using so many TextViews inside ScrollView, so i switched to RecyclerView and i used WebView instead of TextViews. That improved performance.

Comment: any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For list of items it is better to use RecyclerView than LinearLayout inside ScrollView with hardcoded number of views inside it. LinearLayout will take more time to compute everything and views will not be recycled when they are not shown to user. RecyclerView would be better solution for this as it does recycling of views and performance will be better.

Comment: I will be using the same amount of text with RecyclerView. Are you sue that will make it load faster?  And i would like to use WebViews instead of TextViews so that i can use html tags.

Comment: Amount of text doesn't play a role here, it is basically more optimised way of showing collection of views(items) than using LinearLayout. TextView can do job for you if you want to use some of Html tags that it support, if you need more tags than that you can implement Html.TagHandler to interpret them yourself. WebViews are not very optimised and it takes time to render them even if content is small.

Comment: OK i am trying it. Will let you know soon. Thanks! :)

Comment: I tried, it works, but i would lke to use WebViews, because i think WVs look better in my app. Do you have any idea that why it's the first time only after opening the app a WebView will load slow then it or any other WebView will load quickly?

Comment: That is issue with WebView. It needs time to render content.